# c# winforms реализация десктоп приложения с БД

Tags: c#, datagridview

уважаемые люди, помогите разобраться в чем моя грубейшая ошибка , создаю десткоп приложение регистратор журнал писем, БД находится на MySql сервере ( сервер MAMP), при добавлении новой записи в Базу данных выскакивает такая ошибка [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
Namespace registrator
{
    public partial class register : Form
    {

        static string conString = "Server=localhost;Uid=root;Pwd=root;database=register;port=3306";
        MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(conString);
        MySqlCommand cmd;
        MySqlDataAdapter adapter;
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        public register()
        {
            InitializeComponent();


            //DATAGRIDVIEW PROPERTIES

            dataGridView1.ColumnCount = 6;
            dataGridView1.Columns[0].Name = "ID";
            dataGridView1.Columns[1].Name = "дата";
            dataGridView1.Columns[2].Name = "регистрационный номер";
            dataGridView1.Columns[3].Name = "называние";
            dataGridView1.Columns[4].Name = "содержание";
            dataGridView1.Columns[5].Name = "категория";


            dataGridView1.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.Fill;

            //Selection mode

            dataGridView1.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect;
            dataGridView1.MultiSelect = false;


        }

       

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Hide();
            menu menu2 = new menu();
            menu2.Show();
        }

        //INSERT IN TO DB
        private void add(int date,int number,string name,string content,int category)


        {
            // SQL STMT 
            string sql = "INSERT INTO `register`(`ID`, `date`, `number`, `name`, `content`, `category`) VALUES ([value-1],[value-2],[value-3],[value-4],[value-5],[value-6])";
            cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, con);

            //OPEN CONNECTION AND EXEC insert
            try
            {
                con.Open();

                if (cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()>0)
                {
                    clearTxts();
                    MessageBox.Show("successfuly");
                }

                con.Close();

            //    retrieve();
            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                con.Close();
            }
        }

        //ADD TO DGVIEW

        private void populate(int id,int date,string number,String name,string content,string category)
        {
            dataGridView1.Rows.Add(string date, string, number, string name, string content, string category);
        }
        
                // RETRIEVE  FROM DB

        private void retrieve()
        {
            dataGridView1.Rows.Clear();

            //SQL STMT

            string sql = "SELECT * FROM `register` ";
            cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, con);

            //OPEN CON, RETRIEVE, FILL DGWIEW

            try
            {
                con.Open();

                adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                adapter.Fill(dt);

                //LOOP THRU DT
                foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
                {
                    populate(row[0].ToString(), row[1].ToString(), row[2].ToString(), row[3].ToString(), row[4].ToString(), row[5].ToString());
                   
                    
                }

                con.Close();

                //CLEAR DT

                dt.Rows.Clear();
            }

            catch (Exception ex)
                {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);

                con.Close();
            }
            }

        private void populate(string v1, string v2, string v3, string v4, string v5)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }


        //UPDATE DB 

        private void update(int id, int date, int number, string name, string content, int category)
        {


            //SQL STMT 

            string sql = "UPDATE `register` SET `ID`=[value-1],`date`=[value-2],`number`=[value-3],`name`=[value-4],`content`=[value-5],`category`=[value-6] WHERE 1";
          //  string sql = "UPDATE `register` SET `data`='" + дата + "' ,`number`='" + регистрационный номер + "',`name`='" + называние + "', `content`='" + содержание + "',`çategory`='" + категория + "',  WHERE ID=" + id + "";
            cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, con);

            //OPEN CON, UPDATE, RETRIVE DGVIEW

            try
            {
                con.Open();
                adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);

                adapter.UpdateCommand = con.CreateCommand();
                adapter.UpdateCommand.CommandText = sql;

                if(adapter.UpdateCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()>0)
                {
                    clearTxts();
                    MessageBox.Show("добавлено");
                }
                con.Close();

               // retrieve();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                con.Close();
            }
        }

        //DELETE FROM DB
        private void delete(int id)
        {
            //SQLSTMT
            string sql = "DELETE FROM `register` WHERE ID =" + id + "";
            cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, con);

            //OPEN CONNECTION, EXECUTE DELETE, CLOSE CONNECTION

            try
            {
                con.Open();

                adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                adapter.DeleteCommand = con.CreateCommand();
                adapter.DeleteCommand.CommandText = sql;

                // PROMPT FOR CONFIRMATION 

                if(MessageBox.Show("sure ??","DELETE",MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel,MessageBoxIcon.Warning)==DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    if(cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()>0)
                    {
                        clearTxts();
                        MessageBox.Show("удален");
                    }
                }

                con.Close();

           //     retrieve();

                }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                con.Close();
            }

        }

        //clear txtx

        private void clearTxts()
        {
            date.Text = "";
            number.Text = "";
            name.Text = "";
            content.Text = "";
            category.Text = "";
                                                      
        }

        private void dataGridView1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            date.Text = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
            number.Text = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[2].Value.ToString();
            name.Text = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[3].Value.ToString();
            content.Text = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[4].Value.ToString();
            category.Text = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[5].Value.ToString();
        }

        private void buttondobawit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            add(date.Text, number.Text, name.Text, content.Text, category.Text);
        }

        private void buttonudalit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string selected = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Value.ToString();   
            int id = Convert.ToInt32(selected);

            delete(id);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Как и сказано в тексте ошибки на вашем скриншоте, у вас неверный SQL-запрос.
Согласно [документации MySql](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-programming-prepared-preparing.html) ваша функция должна выглядеть примерно так

```
//INSERT IN TO DB
private void add(int date, int number, string name, string content, int category)
{
    // SQL STMT 
    string sql = "INSERT INTO register (date, number, name, content, category) VALUES (@date, @number, @name, @content, @category)";
    cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, con);
    cmd.Prepare();

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date", date);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@number", number);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", name);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@content", content);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@category", category);

    //OPEN CONNECTION AND EXEC insert
    try
    {
        con.Open();

        if (cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() > 0)
        {
            clearTxts();
            MessageBox.Show("successfuly");
        }

        con.Close();

        //    retrieve();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        con.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Я бы вынес `con.Close()` в `finally` еще, чтобы не повторять 2 раза. А еще лучше использовать `using` для `IDisposable` объектов.